# Why does my kick command not work? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Kicked", description=f"You have been Kicked from {member.guild.name}.")
    embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
    embed.add_field(name="Moderator:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.name}#{ctx.message.author.discriminator}")
    await member.send(embed=embed)  
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    success = discord.Embed(title="Successfully Kicked", description=f"You Kicked {member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
    success.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
    await ctx.reply(embed=success)
```

this is the same for ban, it worked before i added the embeds

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Are you on the right library version to use `.reply`? I also see that your code can be adapted in many ways. You can simply use `ctx.author` and you will get `Name#0000` as an output and the guild can be `ctx.guild.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `await ctx.send()` instead like so:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Kicked", description=f"You have been Kicked from {member.guild.name}.")
    embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
    embed.add_field(name="Moderator:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.name}#{ctx.message.author.discriminator}")
    await member.send(embed=embed)  
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    success = discord.Embed(title="Successfully Kicked", description=f"You Kicked {member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
    success.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=success)
```